# Jpeg, png, gif format images are not displaying in any browser

Tags: html, eclipse, adobe, adobe-illustrator

I am designing a website, I am creating some images for that website by using the illustrator and photoshop software, storing those images in jpeg, png and gif formats. I am writing code for the website in the eclipse software, because I am using jsp and javascript to debug it.

My problem is, the images I have created and linked to the html file are displaying in the Eclipse browser (It is an inbuilt browser to check the code). But, they're not displaying in any other browsers like IE, CROME, FIREFOX.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can somebody show you the path when you don't put the code you have written here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off hand, it sounds like you don't have the images linked properly. Aside from checking the code itself, I'd view source in Firefox ( <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  + <kbd>U</kbd> ) and try clicking on the img src urls. If clicking them doesn't load the actual image file, your links are wrong.

Comment: That was my first thought too, but if they're building and checking the site locally, the file:// _should_ still work IIRC. It's been a long time since I ever accidentally linked to a local file.

Comment: If you are working locally, you should still have a webserver

Comment: thank u all. i would check it again. But now i am using dreamweaver to develop, it works good for all browser and accepts all kinds of images.